# How to get the pixel value on the a-axis and b-axis of CIELAB image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, colors, rgb

i converted a BGR image to LAB color system, and i want to know the exact value of a pixel in the LAB image on the a-axis and b-axis.
as shiwn below in the code, when i use `dst.get(0, 3)[0]` to display the pixel value of a pixel in the LAB image, i receive a scalr value, while what i want to get is, the pixel value in the LAB image on the a-axis and the b-axis.

i need it to computed an ecludian distance.
Please let me know how to do it

*code**:

```
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(bgrMat, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2Lab);
    ImageUtils.showMat(dst, "");

    Log.D(TAG, "main", "dst.dump() \n" + dst.dump());
    Log.D(TAG, "main", "dst.get(0, 3): " + dst.get(0, 3)[0]);
```

**outPut**:

```
    1: Debug: MainClass -> main: dst.dump() 
    [1, 128, 128, 7, 128, 128, 19, 128, 128, 47, 128, 128, 58, 128, 128, 28, 128, 128, 8, 128, 128, 16, 128, 128, 17, 128, 128, 18, 128, 128;
    2, 128, 128, 2, 128, 128, 15, 128, 128, 46, 128, 128, 55, 128, 128, 40, 128, 128, 27, 128, 128, 27, 128, 128, 25, 128, 128, 24, 128, 128;
    1, 128, 128, 3, 128, 128, 18, 128, 128, 34, 128, 128, 34, 128, 128, 41, 128, 128, 47, 128, 128, 39, 128, 128, 30, 128, 128, 23, 128, 128;
    9, 128, 128, 10, 128, 128, 19, 128, 128, 25, 128, 128, 17, 128, 128, 23, 128, 128, 41, 128, 128, 51, 128, 128, 24, 128, 128, 9, 128, 128;
    11, 128, 128, 9, 128, 128, 27, 128, 128, 58, 128, 128, 63, 128, 128, 43, 128, 128, 36, 128, 128, 48, 128, 128, 23, 128, 128, 5, 128, 128;
    5, 128, 128, 9, 128, 128, 36, 128, 128, 78, 128, 128, 103, 128, 128, 93, 128, 128, 71, 128, 128, 61, 128, 128, 19, 128, 128, 1, 128, 128;
    5, 128, 128, 10, 128, 128, 39, 128, 128, 68, 128, 128, 82, 128, 128, 87, 128, 128, 83, 128, 128, 73, 128, 128, 16, 128, 128, 1, 128, 128;
    1, 128, 128, 1, 128, 128, 41, 128, 128, 77, 128, 128, 57, 128, 128, 34, 128, 128, 38, 128, 128, 40, 128, 128, 27, 128, 128, 9, 128, 128;
    5, 128, 128, 5, 128, 128, 47, 128, 128, 87, 128, 128, 57, 128, 128, 27, 128, 128, 16, 128, 128, 9, 128, 128, 19, 128, 128, 39, 128, 128;
    11, 128, 128, 12, 128, 128, 58, 128, 128, 94, 128, 128, 67, 128, 128, 47, 128, 128, 35, 128, 128, 18, 128, 128, 24, 128, 128, 42, 128, 128]
    2: Debug: MainClass -> main: dst.get(0, 3): 47.0
```

Comment: This looks like OpenCV... why the `matlab` tag? Also, please tag with the language you're using (Java?).

Comment: Of course you're getting a scalar, you're printing only the first element of the array.

Comment: @beaker but the value i am getting is not in the image displayed above as pixel values!! would you please tell me how can i get the corresponding value on the a-axis and b-axis

Comment: Sure it is. In the dump, look at the 10th value. That's the `47` you're getting. That's `L`. `dst.get(0,3)[1]` will be `a` (128).

Comment: @beaker but why i am getting the value of the 1th pixel? i want dst.get(0,3)!! also i tried the following dst.get(0,3)[0] = 47, and dst.get(0,3)[1]=128 and dst.get(0,3)[2] = 128. would you please explain why i am getting these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the structure of a 3-channel OpenCV Mat and the output of `dump`.

If you look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#how-the-image-matrix-is-stored-in-the-memory) you'll find the following diagram which shows the internal structure of a 3-channel Mat.

[image]

The table is colored blue, green and red, but it's the same structure for any 3-channel Mat, including CIELAB.

You'll notice that each column is made up of 3 values. In a BGR image, these would be the blue, green and red components of the pixel. In your case, they're the `L`, `a`, and `b` components.

Now look at the dump of your Mat. It has 10 rows, but 30 columns. I'm willing to bet that the size of your Mat is `10x10` with 3 channels. As shown in the diagram, the reason the dump has 30 columns instead of 10 is that the 3 components of each pixel are listed consecutively. Here's the first row of your dump:

```
[1, 128, 128, 7, 128, 128, 19, 128, 128, 47, 128, 128, 58, 128, 128, 28, 128, 128, 8, 128, 128, 16, 128, 128, 17, 128, 128, 18, 128, 128; ..
```

The first pixel at `(0,0)` has `Lab` components of `1, 128, 128`.
The second pixel at `(0,1)` has `Lab` components of `7, 128, 128`.
The third pixel is `19, 128, 128`. These **3 pixels** take up the first **9 values** in your dump.
The fourth pixel at `(0,3)` (starting at the 10th value) is `47, 128, 128`.

That's why `dst.get(0,3)[0] = 47`,
`dst.get(0,3)[1]=128` and
`dst.get(0,3)[2] = 128`.

Normally, to access these pixels individually, you would `get` them into an array of the same type as the image. If you have a `CV_8UC3`, for example, you would put the pixel into a `byte[]`:

```
byte[] interestingPixel = dst.get(0, 3);
```

Now, for pixel `(0, 3)`,

```
interestingPixel[0] = L
interestingPixel[1] = a
interestingPixel[2] = b
```